FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory Ec2 nodejs pm2
I am using ec2 machine and running nodejs application with pm2 and i am facing this issue
0|backend  | <--- Last few GCs --->
0|backend  |
0|backend  | [432704:0x7034870]  3263111 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 1918.1 (1953.3) -> 1917.7 (1954.0) MB, 801.2 / 0.0 ms  (+ 295.2 ms in 86 steps since start of marking, biggest step 22.1 ms, walltime since start of marking 1334 ms) (average mu = 0.347, current mu = 0.4[432704:0x7034870]  3264816 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 1918.7 (1954.0) -> 1917.9 (1954.5) MB, 1697.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.190, current mu = 0.004) allocation failure; scavenge might not succeed
0|backend  |
0|backend  |
0|backend  | <--- JS stacktrace --->
0|backend  |
0|backend  | FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
0|backend  |  1: 0xb95be0 node::Abort() [node /home/ubuntu/project/backend/dist/main.js]
0|backend  |  2: 0xa9a7f8  [node /home/ubuntu/project/backend/dist/main.js]
0|backend  |  3: 0xd6f5b0 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node /home/ubuntu/project/backend/dist/main.js]
0|backend  |  4: 0xd6f957 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node /home/ubuntu/project/backend/dist/main.js]
0|backend  |  5: 0xf4ceb5  [node /home/ubuntu/project/backend/dist/main.js]
0|backend  |  6: 0xf5f38d v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node /home/ubuntu/project/backend/dist/main.js]
0|backend  |  7: 0xf39a7e v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node /home/ubuntu/project/backend/dist/main.js]
0|backend  |  8: 0xf3ae47 v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node /home/ubuntu/project/backend/dist/main.js]
0|backend  |  9: 0xf1c04a v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [node /home/ubuntu/project/backend/dist/main.js]
0|backend  | 10: 0x12e139f v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node /home/ubuntu/project/backend/dist/main.js]
0|backend  | 11: 0x170e079  [node /home/ubuntu/project/backend/dist/main.js]
0|backend  | (node:432915) NOTE: We are formalizing our plans to enter AWS SDK for JavaScript (v2) into maintenance mode in 2023.
0|backend  |
0|backend  | Please migrate your code to use AWS SDK for JavaScript (v3).
0|backend  | For more information, check the migration guide at https://a.co/7PzMCcy

on saying
pm2 monit

it is showing

is this total heap size ?
i have tried passing this as well
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=1048;

and even
pm2 restart 0 --node-args="--max-old-space-size=1048"

so what can be the issue and how can i check my heap size assigned and used?
Update1
Regarding files i am donig 2 things
From frontend user can upload the csv file, and i am reading as an array object like this, is it correct way?
import * as CSV from 'csv-string';
const fileContent = paymentFile.buffer.toString('utf-8');
const centerlinkPayments = CSV.parse(fileContent);

and some other pdf files to upload on s3 like this
async upload(file, basePath: string): Promise<string> {

    const fileName = this._getRandomFileName(file)
    const bucketFileKey = `${basePath}/${fileName}`;

    const params: AWS.S3.PutObjectRequest = {
      Bucket: this.bucketName,
      Key: bucketFileKey,
      Body: file.buffer
    };

    this.logger.log(`Uploading ${bucketFileKey}`);

    await this.s3.putObject(params).promise();
    this.logger.log(`Uploaded ${bucketFileKey}`);
    return bucketFileKey;
  }

and on controller side i have recieving files like this
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('paymentFile'))
  @Post("/url")
  uploadFile(@UploadedFile() paymentFile): Promise<ApiResponseDto> {
    return this.paymentService.uploadFile(paymentFile);
  }

Is this buffer thing is ok? if user is upload 50mb file then that 50mb will be used from heap memory ? in this can stream be helpful?

what can be the issue your unseen code is gobbling up the RAMS?

yes, there are loophols but for now any temp solution like increasing heap?

The issue is you're running out of memory. Make your program use less memory, or e.g. use a larger machine.

How long does it take for your current code to fail? What size memory does your EC2 instance have?

4gb ram overall

You're not showing how those two bits of code you edited in are related at all.

Anyway, see this article on how to profile memory use.

@AKX thanks, i have updated the question regarding these 2 code snippets, i think i am not creating a stream instead loading the buffer in one go, but not sure

Well, yes, if you have a .buffer, that's not a stream.

@AKX can you suggest in both cases, how it should be done?

How do I reproduce this?  Your question should provide code that reproduces the issue by providing a [mre].  As it stands I have no way to debug this.  The code that you showed does not, on its own, elicit the error you have shown.  Although I do see that you have file.buffer  You should probably stream files rather than relying on the entirety of the file to reside in memory in a single buffer.

@CodeGuru No, not without knowing e.g. what you'd do with centerlinkPayments. I also don't know what your file is for the second argument.

@Wyck i have added the code and explantion

As discussed in https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload , Nest's file uploads use Multer. If you can access a .buffer, that seems to imply you're using Multer's memory storage.
